# Vim's visual mode guidance

Tags: vim

When in Vim's visual mode (regular or line), what can you do?

Is it simply for selected part of a line, an entire line, or a block of text?

And then you either copy/past/search/replace on the selected text or are there more tricks to it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are correct. Visual Mode is generally used for moving/searching/copying/deleting blocks of text.

However some tricks you can do is pass that block of text to external programs, such as sort.

Assuming you have selected text with visual mode, you can call(for example):

```
!sort
```

This will pass the highlighted text, and pass that text to the sort unix command(because of the '!'). Once it sorts the text, it will then replace what you originally highlighted in visual mode with the sorted text.

Comment: You can do that as well. I was just giving an example of calling an external command.

Answer (score 1):

I often select a column with visual block and insert text for each line of at the selection (with `I` for before the selection or `A` for after).